# distutils setup script under linux - permission issue

Tags: python, linux, distutils, setup.py

So I created a `setup.py` script for my python program with `distutils` and I think it behaves a bit strange. First off it installs all `data_files` into `/usr/local/my_directory` by default which is a bit weird since this isn't a really common place to store data, is it?
I changed the path to `/usr/share/my_directory/`. But now I'm not able to write to the database inside that directory and I can't set required permission from within `setup.py` neither since the actual database file has not been created when I run it.

Is my approach wrong? Should I use another tool for distributing?
Because at least for Linux, writing a simple setup `sh` script seems easier to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate solution is to invoke setup.py with --prefix=/the/path/you/want.

A better approach would be to include the data as package_data. This way they will be installed along side your python package and you'll find it much easier to manage it (find paths etc).

Comment: Both options are not working. I'm still not able to access the database. /usr/share/  is owned by root by default so it's not that simple I fear.

Comment: I meant something like python setup.py --prefix ~/myapp. Regarding the second, the database will be installed relative to your package.